# Juniper srx-100-b doesn't boot anymore

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-srx, srx

I hope someone can help me. this is the case:

I have a Juniper srx-100-b and I tried to configure this device completely from scratch. What I have done, in u-boot mode, I perform the command 'erase all' (twice). Now i'm lost the partitions on the device, so the device can not load JunOS.

When I connect with the console cable, I don't see any post messages.

My questions is: Is there a way to recover these partitions and install JunOS on a complete empty device.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The correct procedure for this would be to run `request system zeroize` from the cli.

Does the device still boot to U-boot when you restart it? If so maybe you can follow this [procedure](http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB14175&actp=search) to re-install junos.

Comment: No the device doesn't boot to u-boot that is the whole problem. When I connect with the console cable, I don't see any output.

Comment: I've just entered U-boot to check on the command that you used and it mentions this:  
`erase all - erase all FLASH banks`  
I think you bricked the device and at this point only Juniper could help you.

Comment: @xpto is correct, Juniper will issue you an RMA under a valid warranty.  If you haven't created a JTAC case, you should.

Answer (score 0):

The correct process for beginning with a blank configuration is:

```
user@hostname# delete
user@hostname# set system root-authentication plain-text-password
user@hostname# commit
user@hostname> request system reboot
```

Using

```
request system zeroize
```

Will give you a default configuration if you read here:
http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos15.1/topics/reference/command-summary/request-system-zeroize.html